# Popup dialog spinner with bondedDevices is null

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, android-bluetooth

When trying to make a popup dialog with paired bluetooth devices in a spinner, my app crashes upon opening. See this code for the xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">
    
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_devices"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bConnectBtn"
        android:text="CONNECT"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

In the code below here, I call a function that checks for bonded devices and then puts it in the spinner:

```
private fun onBluetoothEnabled() {
    val bondedDevices = bluetoothAdapter?.bondedDevices
    if (bondedDevices != null) {
        val bondedAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, bondedDevices.map { it.name })
        bondedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        spinner_devices.adapter = bondedAdapter

        bConnectBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val device = bondedDevices.toList()[spinner_devices.selectedItemPosition]
            setupClient(device)
        }
    }
}
```

Here I show the dialog:

```
val bluetoothView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bluetoothdialog, null)
val bluetoothDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)

bluetoothDialog.setTitle("Paired Devices")
bluetoothDialog.setView(bluetoothView)
bluetoothDialog.setCancelable(false)
bluetoothDialog.setNeutralButton("TEMP CLOSE") { _, _ -> }

bluetoothDialog.show()
```

Some extra details about this, this works just fine when the spinner is in the main activity xml, but when I put the spinner in a popup dialog xml file, it crashes upon start. When I add `? or !!` to `spinner_devices?.adapter` it works but doesn't fill the spinner with the bonded devices which makes sense because it allows null now.

When I debug my code, I can see that the `bondedApapter` gets filled with paired bluetooth devices, but when it gets to the `spinner_devices.adapter` it is `null`. Any guesses on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: where does the `spinner_devices` come from. Please add all relevant code to be able to track the source of issue.

Comment: It is litterly in the code above.. It's in the XML as a Spinner

Comment: I know that it is in the xml. I wan't to see the code where you initialize the `spinner_devices` object. Because in your post I can only see two separate code snippet in which the order of the execution is unknown. That's why it is important to see all the relevant code. From the error, we can only guess you access the `spinner_devices` object before you get a reference from xml (without initializing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering. I was able to fix it and made it a bit more usefull by being able to click on a bluetooth device and make it connect. See code below for full code:

```
private fun showPairedDevicesPopup() {
    val bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()
    val pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice> = bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices

    // Create a list of device names
    val deviceNames = ArrayList<String>()
    pairedDevices.forEach { deviceNames.add(it.name) }

    // Create an array adapter to display the list of device names
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceNames)

    // Build the alert dialog
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("Paired Devices")
    builder.setCancelable(false)
    builder.setAdapter(adapter) { _, which ->
        // Get the selected device
        val selectedDevice = pairedDevices.elementAt(which)

        // Attempt to connect to the selected device
        val socket: BluetoothSocket?
        try {
            socket = selectedDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"))
            socket.connect()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // Failed to connect to the device
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    // Show the alert dialog
    val dialog = builder.create()

    dialog.show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some object initialization when you tries to bind adapter from `AlertDialog`. Checkout the below code that is working fine.

```
val bluetoothView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bluetoothdialog, null)
val bluetoothDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)
bluetoothDialog.setTitle("Paired Devices")
bluetoothDialog.setView(bluetoothView)
bluetoothDialog.setCancelable(false)
bluetoothDialog.setNeutralButton("TEMP CLOSE") { _, _ ->}
bluetoothDialog.show()
```

**//get views from inflated layout

val spinnerDevices = bluetoothView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_devices)

val bConnectBtn = bluetoothView.findViewById(R.id.bConnectBtn)**

```
 //bind adapter
val bondedAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, bondedDevices.map { it.name })
               bondedAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
spinnerDevices.adapter = bondedAdapter

bConnectBtn.setOnClickListener {
val device = bondedDevices.toList()[spinnerDevices.selectedItemPosition]
Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"Connection to:${device.name}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

}

Comment: Tried this before but when I do this, the .adapter says "Unresolved Reference: adapter"